# Duplicate method onClick(View) in type new View.OnClickListener(){} When using 2 buttons Android SDK

Tags: android

I want to use 2 buttons for my app.

One for entering a value in a EditText field, and one for opening another class.

However, I get this error: Duplicate method onClick(View) in type new View.OnClickListener(){}

What do I have to change?

```
package com.example.app;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected TextView textField;
        EditText ed;
            Button b;
            int number;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Button page2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.page2);

                page2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            }

            public void onClick(View view){
                number = Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
                if(number < 11) ed.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                else if(number > 10 && number < 21) ed.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                else ed.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/enter_values" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/page2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="page2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Check density" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="Density" />
```

Comment: You need delete android:onClick="onClick" line

Comment: I just did but still get the same error.

Comment: I get the suggestion to rename "onClick" method

Comment: Please fix your indentation and remove the double-spacing.

Comment: ooo I got your mistake now. You cannot create method your listener you  need add new listener to your new button like your page button

Answer (score 1):

you can create one setOnClickListener for each button, for example:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu2.class);
               startActivity(intent);
            }
});


   button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
               //do whatever you want 
            }
});
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
package com.example.app;

// interface of OnClickListener
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{ {
    protected TextView textField;
    EditText ed;
        Button b;
        int number;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Button page2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.page2);
            ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            // set button listeners 
            // each button should have its own listener
            Button .setOnClickListener(this);
            b .setOnClickListener(this);

                }
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {    
        // if button page2 is clicked
        case R.id.page2:        
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),menu2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;    
        //if button b is clicked
        case R.id.button1:          
             number = Integer.parseInt(ed.getText().toString());
            if(number < 11) ed.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            else if(number > 10 && number < 21) ed.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            else ed.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;   
    }  
}
```

}

i hope it help

Answer (score 0):

If you want declare onClick on your xml

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.page2);
    page2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //for your pageButton
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    //for your button1
}
```